# How to trigger alert when items are unavailable?

Tags: zabbix

Using Zabbix, how can I trigger an alert if an item is unreachable (e.g. 'ZBX_NOTSUPPORTED' or any error that is traced when the zabbix agent could not provide the expected item format) ?

The goal is to prevent hosts to silently fail on retrieving data on items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/config/notifications/unsupported_item):

> Receiving notifications on unsupported items is supported since Zabbix
>   2.2.
>
> It is part of the concept of internal events in Zabbix, allowing users
>   to be notified on these occasions. Internal events reflect a change of
>   state:
>
> - when items go from 'normal' to 'unsupported' (and back) when triggers
> - go from 'normal' to 'unknown' (and back) when low-level discovery
> - rules go from 'normal' to 'unsupported' (and back)

Comment: Thank you, i'll mark as accepted However, are notifications the only way know to alert such problems ? Routing these notifications to the dashboard, and present them as alerts would have been more useful in my case.

Comment: You can try with a `nodata` trigger (https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/appendix/triggers/functions): "Since Zabbix 3.2, nodata(), date(), dayofmonth(), dayofweek(), now() and time() functions are calculated for unsupported items, too"

Comment: Would it be possible to deploy these kind of trigger for every items on a template ? Or do I have to create theme for each item I want to monitor ?

Comment: As an ugly workaround you can react to an unsupported item with a script which uses zabbix_sender to write something like "Alert on {ITEM.NAME}" on a generic item, then trigger on it

Answer (score 1):

when item is unsupported, it means that the item has not received any data.So you can use nodata() funcation.

nodata(sec)
    Checking for no data received.
Supported value types: any

Returns:
1 - if no data received during the defined period of time
0 - otherwise